# SQL: Fetching a table summary/statistics

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table that I want to have several statistics(summary) on it. The table name is "jobs" and some of the needed statistics are:

The number of jobs that are active, the number of jobs that are in inactive status, the number of jobs which need male force, the number of jobs which pay more than x amount per month, ...

I need a query to pull all this statistics form the "jobs" table and put in into **one-row** result. Query result should look something like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
| stats1_column | stats2_column | stats3_column | ... |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
| x             | y             | z             | ... |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
```

After all, do you think I **fetch table summary** properly like what I'm doing? Or I'm wrong and there is a better way?

I'm working on a PHP project using MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably use `COUNT()` aggregate function for every category and then `UNION ALL` and then covert rows to column by `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Below is the possible query that you could have:

```
SELECT  
GROUP_CONCAT(if(Category = 'Active Jobs', CategoryCount, NULL)) AS 'Active_Jobs', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(Category = 'Inactive Jobs', CategoryCount, NULL)) AS 'Inactive_Jobs'  
FROM
(
 SELECT 'Active Jobs' as Category, COUNT(*) as CategoryCount
 FROM Jobs
 WHERE Status = 'Active'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Inactive Jobs' as Category, COUNT(*) as CategoryCount
 FROM Jobs
 WHERE Status = 'Inactive'
) tbl
```

See Sample <kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af1a9/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(active, 1, 0)) stats_active, 
    SUM(IF(active, 0, 1)) stats_inactive,
    SUM(IF(needs_male, 1, 0)) stats_needs_male,
    SUM(IF(pay > 1000, 1, 0)) stats_well_paid,
.... and so on ....
FROM jobs
```

The problem with this approach/query is that it is inefficient because it scans the entire table. If the table has lots of rows, performance will be affected.

If the table has proper indexes, a more efficient way to do it is to run a query for each stat you need. In PHP this would be something like (ignore typos):

```
$stats = array(
    'stats_active' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs WHERE active',
    'stats_inactive' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs WHERE NOT active', 
    'stats_needs_male' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs WHERE needs_male',  
    .... others here ....
);
$result = (object) array();
foreach($stats as $name => $query) {
    $result->$name = db_fetch_single_result($query); // database specific code goes here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is kind of a hard read, but what I think you want, but could be wrong is like this?

```
Select
stats1_column,
stats2_column,
stats3_colum
From 
Jobs
```

This is pretty basic that why I am unsure if this is what you want.

Comment: could you kindly be more specific in providing an answer to the question?